# Is Berlin experiencing a decrease in public activity during summer time (July and August)?

Tags: berlin, summer

**Context:** I am looking into settling down in Berlin and I would like to know what to expect from summer time in term of public activity/cultural events.

**What I've observed:** I've noticed each city has its own pace during summer time, some cities becoming more active (more people in the city, more cultural/social/outdoor activities), some others becoming more quiet (less people in the city, businesses opened limited hours) or not being impacted at all.

**Question:** Is Berlin experiencing a decrease in public activity during summer time (July and August)?

**I am especially interested by the following aspects:**

1. Are the streets noticeably less crowded during summer time?
2. Is the city known to experience an increase in social/cultural activity during July and August? (example: outdoor cinemas, streets/parks festivals, music festivals, fireworks, ...)
3. Is there times during summer when public places (especially coffee places, libraries and co-working spaces) are expected to be open only during limited hours (or to be closed)?

Comment: You think Wellington is *quieter* in the summer??

Comment: Clearly, the meanings of "vibrant" and "quiet" as used in this question are a matter of opinion.

Comment: @MarkMayo: sorry I wasn't actually referring to the full summer period, but more specifically to Dec 22-Jan 11 where (understandably) many places (libraries, coffees, co-working spaces, pubs) are closed or opened limited hours. I'll edit my question to reflect this fact. (Also, please note that the wording is very subjective.)

Comment: Might be worth having a read of the [help] on what questions not to ask - subjective questions often get closed :/

Comment: In my experience, Berlin in the summer is hot, but there's lots of stuff on! It isn't Paris ;-)

Comment: regarding 3: my experience in Berlin and next to all (larger) German cities I've been to is that such public places will continue to have their usual opening hours during all summer - either because tourist numbers are high (Berlin) or because the holiday season increases traffic from locals (both Berlin and many smaller cities)..

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr and greyshade, it's exactly the kind of insights I was looking for :) The question being [on hold], I've made some modifications trying to make it more objectively answerable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some things do have a kind of break during the summer (one that comes to mind are the opera houses but isn't it true of opera houses everywhere?) but shops will have normal opening hours. Cafe are definitely open, I don't think libraries have limited hours, don't know about co-working spaces.

Some offices might be a little less busy but it's a large city with many tourists so it's not like it's closing down in the summer like a ski resort. The crowd might be a bit different but the streets certainly aren't empty.

On the other hand, there are a number of summer-only things to enjoy in Berlin: beer gardens, outdoor cinemas, beach bars on the Spree, floating swimming pool, al fresco dining, biking and other activities in the lakes and parks around the city, etc. so it's definitely worth experiencing in this season as well.